# Хочу сделать сайт с помощью VScode и Airtable, подскажите как подключить базу данных airtable к VScode, возможно ли так сделать вообще?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Хочу сделать сайт с помощью VScode и Airtable, подскажите как подключить базу данных airtable к VScode, возможно ли так сделать вообще?

Comment: [Может это то, что ищете](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qwtel.sqlite-viewer)

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы о подстановке ключевых слов из сущесностей БД, то, вероятно, нет, но можете проверить в проектах (и плагинах) от JetBrains (у них парсятся пакеты, касается ли это JavaScript или Java, к примеру; по аналогии, может быть, есть такой плагин для БД, но факт, что именно Вашей).